# Set Callback for VideoView controller in Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

Is it possible to listen to the pause/play button on the media controller of VideoView?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement the interface `MediaController.MediaPlayerControl` and register the interface with the mediaController instance using the method - `setMediaPlayer`